# Screen processes continue to run but can't find the original screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm new to setting processes running via ssh on a server. To allow me to step away and return to them I'm trying to run them in a screen session.

```
# ssh onto server
ssh myid@server.co.uk

# Start screen session
screen -S myscreen

# Set the process running.
gatk CombineGVCFs \
   -R "/refs/hg38/gatk download/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta" \
   --variant "/data/MSH3repeat_S1_L001_g.vcf.gz" \
   --variant "/data/20201028_CCDG_14151_B01_GRM_WGS_2020-08-05_chr5.recalibrated_variants.vcf.gz" \
   -O "/data/cohort.g.vcf.gz"
```

When I check the screens that are running immediately with `screen -ls` then I can see `myscreen`. However, when I switch off the computer and then return the next day I run `screen -ls` and it says no sockets.

I think it might be something to do with the fact when I set up a  new screen with e.g. `screen -S myscreen` I always get this error:

```
  File "/usr/bin/pixstor-notify", line 64
    print f.read().strip()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(base) skgtmdf@rds-gw-007:~ $
```

But I don't know what it means!

However, the screen is clearly still there as the output files continue to accumulate in the output destination!!

##############################
Updating as per comment
##############################

## 1. ssh onto server

## 2. Start a screen

```
$ screen -S demo_error
```

## 3. Screen session opens with the error:

```
Last login: Sat Dec 18 10:59:31 on ttys003

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Its not clear from your question when the error is occurring (when starting screen, after executing your command in screen, or when returning to a detached screen). Also, are you shutting down your own computer or the server? Are you properly detaching from screen before you logout? The error given above probably isnt your root cause but likely related. `pixstor` appears to be related to some sort of NAS - a clue? Try running screen with logging enabled eg  `screen -S myscreen -L` - will create a filename starting with `screenlog` in current directory with any output/errors.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated above to clarify what I see. I am detaching from the screen session with Ctrl+a then d before closing the ssh session. I then either ssh back onto the server, or restart the computer and ssh back onto the server, and `screen -ls` shows no sockets. I don't shut down the server.